# How long for a visual design?

Tags: visual-design, timeline

How long would it take you to do a visual design mockup of a dashboard (one-page) in say photoshop?  This does not include any research related to it.  Would you spend one day or more like a week?  I am curious of how others estimate time and what is expended in the industry.

Comment: Welcome to ux.stackexchange; your question is impossible to answer as there are too many variables involve. As the help section states - this is a site where ideally a question can have only one correct answer. It is highly likely the question will be closed for being primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by no research? So you already have the wireframes and navigation thought out?

1 week seems really long for just a dashboard. Assuming you already know what direction you want to take it (in terms of color scheme, layout, and typography), I wouldn't spend more than a day. If you have to detail all the interactions for the dashboard, then that would obviously take longer. How long? It depends how complex your dashboard is.